# Is it possible to load an image from it's thumbnail to it's high quality with an animation.

Tags: android, picasso

I have both thumbnail and real images, by now, loading thumbnail first so that user don't have to wait, then after show its real (high quality) image.
But It should not be like this.
Blur to High quality with nice animations.
using Picasso for Image loading.

Comment: you can set a thumbnail as a placeholder in Picasso. This way it will animate from thumb to full quality once loaded. But the animation is quite simple

Comment: @VladMatvienko Amazing !! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Vlad Matvienko

```
Picasso.with(context)
   .load(thumb) // thumbnail url goes here
   .into(imageView, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(url) // image url goes here
                    .placeholder(imageView.getDrawable())
                    .into(imageView);
        }
        @Override
        public void onError() {

        }
    });
```

This is how it roll.